# PCA and OLS regression to transform to interest rate risk?

Tags: risk, regression, interest-rate-swap, risk-models, pca

I’ve been working on different interest rate risk transformation methods for swaps and was interested in implementing PCA & OLS regression. I’m looking to bucket my exposure in all tenors to curves and flies of my choice.

For example, If I has risk in every tenor, [1,2,3,4,5,6,etc…],

Using OLS or PCA, how could I transform my risk which shows me my risk in different curves and flies e.g. (3s5s10s, 3s10s, 3s4s5s, etc)

I’ve found it difficult to find relevant literature and resources regarding these methods, any insight or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: similar question here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/49528/29443

Comment: or here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/76741/29443

Comment: You might also want to look at  https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/68407  and https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/60059